# How to limit Access-Control-Allow-Origin to a specific path?

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-4

I have a website that servies ads via javascript. So, I basically allow the user to include my script.... :

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/ads.js" ></script>
<script>
    MYADDS.insertAdvert(); 
</script>
```

The problem is, I kept getting: "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin" Errors. That was until I added this to my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Problem is, this opens up my entire site and is probably a security risk. So, seeing as the ads.js file actually only does an ajax request to:

```
http://www.example.com/place/where/my/adds/are/fed/from
```

How can I make the above htaccess rule only apply to that path? Keep in mind, it's not an actualy directory, so I can't put the htaccess file in that folder. It's actually a "virtual path". The site is built using Laravel and therefore does the typical laravel path rewriting. Here's teh full htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: So Laravel serves the content from that specific path as well? If so, then why not just output the header from within Laravel directly, that is definitively easier then doing it via Apache config …

Comment: So specify the headers via PHP. That makes more sense. Lemme give it a bash.

Comment: Was as easy as doing this => $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

Answer (score -5, accepted):

It was as easy as doing this:

```
$response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Comment: This does not answer at all the question. In fact it does the same, it allows it for the whole world. One better solution would be instead of "*" setting it to "http://www.example.com", but even then it would allow from the whole domain, and he wanted to allow it from a specific path only. This is my problem as well: I would like to serve static content from a free public host, that includes the index.html, but the requests would go to my site. So in my site I'd like not to let the whole free webhost, only from my path

Comment: Your answer is completely the opposite of what you are asking. This is misleading and wasteful to people who are actually looking for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following two line in your htaccess also

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

So your additional htaccess will be like the following

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```